# Replace an SVG image onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

```
<svg style="position: absolute;">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="image" width="1" height="1" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <image xlink:href='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Fulmer_Falls_Closeup_3000px.jpg' width="100" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

So within my SVG I have an `href` link pointing to a random image I found on the internet. I'm trying to change this link, so on click of an element it changes.

**JQUERY**

```
var selectedEl = $('#myID li');    
selectedEl.on('click', function () {
    var mySVG = $('#image');
});
```

But I have no idea how I can update the link. I've tried using `attr` to update but to no avail.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that `selectedEl` works, since the html code is missing, the following should do the trick. The `attr` method should change any given attribute name.

```
selectedEl.on('click', function() {
  var mySVG = $('#image image');
  $(mySVG).attr('xlink:href','the new URL here'); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried the `attr` to update, I must of missed the actual HTML tag from my `mySVG` element :)